Including a project in the ROS build farm
Is there a process to get ROS projects included in the ROS build farm? For example, I think that having a ROS project as a pre-built package such as https://github.com/BrettRD/ros-gst-bridge installable via apt would be extremely nice. Is there some process to follow to evaluate if that is possible?

The official documentation is here.
There is also an instructional video series by The Construct, see here (not sure if it is fully up to date though, as is dates from 2022).
Also, refer to this recent question about joining ros2-gbp release team.
